# In Web service spaces are not allow when data pass into URL using GET method

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf, utf8-decode

I have one WCF web service. I am using get method to insert data. So I am passing all the data into URL like

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Insert_drug_details?x_patient_id={x_patient_id}&drug_name={drug_name}&no_of_pills_given={no_of_pills_given}&no_of_pills_taken={no_of_pills_taken}&any_side_effect={any_side_effect}&date_of_pills_given={date_of_pills_given}&x_trimester={x_trimester}&x_visit_no={x_visit_no}")]
        Stream Insert_drug_details(String x_patient_id, String drug_name, String no_of_pills_given, String no_of_pills_taken, String any_side_effect, String date_of_pills_given, String x_trimester, String x_visit_no);
```

**but when I pass value with space it automatically replace my space to %20 which is wrong data for insertion.**

So From My point of view at the time of insertion I should convert values from 
UTF-8 to nvarchar. Android side all the values are encoded So I just decode value.

This is my Insert method :

```
public Stream Insert_drug_details(String x_patient_id, String drug_name, String no_of_pills_given, String no_of_pills_taken
            , String any_side_effect, String date_of_pills_given, String x_trimester, String x_visit_no)
        {
            int flag = 0;
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                String ResultDrugDetailsString;
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_drug_details", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("x_patient_id", x_patient_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("drug_name", drug_name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("no_of_pills_given", no_of_pills_given);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("no_of_pills_taken", no_of_pills_taken);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("any_side_effect", any_side_effect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date_of_pills_given", date_of_pills_given);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("x_trimester", x_trimester);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("x_visit_no", x_visit_no);
                flag = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (flag == 1 || flag == 2)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("select id from drug_details where patient_id=@patient_id and trimester=@trimester and visit_no=@visit_no", con);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patient_id", x_patient_id);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trimester", x_trimester);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_no", x_visit_no);
                    using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        List<Result_Drug_Details> DrugDetails = null;
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            if (DrugDetails == null)
                            {
                                DrugDetails = new List<Result_Drug_Details>();
                            }
                            Result_Drug_Details obj = new Result_Drug_Details();
                            obj.id = rdr["id"].ToString();
                            DrugDetails.Add(obj);
                        }
                        if (DrugDetails != null)
                        {
                            ResultDrugDetailsString = "{\"drug_details\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DrugDetails, Formatting.Indented) + ",\"isSuccess\":\"1\"}";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ResultDrugDetailsString = "{\"isSuccess\":\"-1\"}";
                        }
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ResultDrugDetailsString));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultDrugDetailsString = "{\"isSuccess\":\"-1\"}";
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ResultDrugDetailsString));
                }
            }
        }
```

**Is there any other feasible solution for it???
How to convert UTF-8 to nvarchar??
Or 
How to decode UTF-8 to nvarchar??**

Comment: Try HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It automatically replaces space with %20 because it is a Web request thus it is  URL Encoded. Hence you need to URL Decode it on the recieving side.

```
String value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(String);
```